# Slim Framework - DELETE e Função do Framework

Tags: php, slim

Estou com problemas com o DELETE do slim, ele apresenta um erro 404, segue o código:

```
<?php

require '../Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');

$app->get('/', function () {
echo "SlimProdutos Welcome";
});


$app->delete('/produtos2/:id','deleteProduto');

$app->run();



function getConn()
{
return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Slim',
'root',
'mxk8mxk9',
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);

}




function deleteProduto($id)
{
$sql = "DELETE FROM produtos WHERE id=:id";
$conn = getConn();
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam("id",$id);
$stmt->execute();
echo "{'message':'Produto apagado'}";
}
```

Eu só uso o http e não uso nenhuma outra página/formulario para chamar ele

Estou abrindo ele assim http://localhost/slimTestes/SlimProdutos/produtos2/111
111 é o id que quero apagar!

Outra dúvida é sobre a função do Slim, ele serve basicamente para usar o POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, etc...com rotas e json, certo ? ele tem outras utilidades ?

Comment: No seu controller consegue ver o valor de `$id`?

Comment: como faço isso ?

Comment: Dentro de `deleteProduto()` faça, `echo $id;` seja se o número é pelo menos exibido.

Comment: não, dá um erro 404 do slim "404 Page Not Found"

Comment: Pra mim tinha que alterar somente para DELETE FROM produtos WHERE id= ?

Answer (score 1):

O Slim é um microframework e sim, ele serve para você mapear URLs de acordo com os métodos GET, POST, DELETE, etc. Você não necessariamente precisa retornar uma resposta em JSON, pode retornar qualquer string que queira mostrar ao seu usuário, pode até usar alguma template engine como - por exemplo - a [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Vou te falar aqui os possíveis problemas que podem estar ocorrendo:

### Seu .htaccess está funcionando?

O primeiro possível problema está no seu arquivo .htaccess (se estiver usando apache). Caso você não tenha um arquivo .htaccess ainda, acredito que esse pode funcionar pra ti (não testei):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /slimTestes/SlimProdutos/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

### Você está acessando a url através do método DELETE?

Você definiu seu route com o método `$app->delete` então se você acessar diretamente pelo navegador não vai funcionar.

#### Como saber se o problema é esse?

Mude o método para `$app->get('/produtos2/:id','deleteProduto')` e acesse pelo navegador através do link que você passou. Se você conseguir acessar a url e a sua função for executada normalmente, você saberá que estava chamando a URL através de um métoro errado (GET ou POST).

#### Como corrigir caso o problema seja o método?

Quando for chamar a sua URL através de AJAX (ou outro método que esteja usando), você precisa informar que está usando o método `DELETE` para a requisição.

A maneira mais fácil de fazer isso, se estiver usando jQuery, é usando o método [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options).

**Exemplo Simples:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/slimTestes/SlimProdutos/produtos2/111',
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // Faça o que quiser com o resultado
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

#### Outros testes que você pode fazer:

1. Altere seu método para: `$app->delete('/produtos2/{id}', 'deleteProduto');`
2. Coloque uma função anônima ao invés de uma string no segundo argumento

Se nada resolver, aconselho dar uma lida na [Documentação Oficial](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/request.html#route-object) do Slim Framework.

Comment: No Slim não é necessário configurar a `.htaccess` para reescrever a URL. Você pode facilmente se referir ao end-point assim: `/index.php/delete`